# Java threads: Calling run() method on the Thread object after start()

Tags: java

I am seeing interesting behavior. I am running this code

```
public class ThreadsTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable mr = new MyRunnable();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(mr);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(mr);
        t1.setName("first");
        t2.setName("second");
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t1.run();
    } 
} 

class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
    for (int i=0; i < 2; i++) {
        System.out.println("Running: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
    }
}
```

The output I get is:

```
Running: first
Running: first
Running: second
Running: second
```

I am expecting to see something similar to this:

```
Running: first
Running: first
Running: second
Running: second
Running: main
Running: main
```

Does anyone knows why I don't see `Running: main` somewhere in my output. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would expect to. Could you explain that?

Comment: Calling run() method on the Thread object `t1.run()` should invoke run method in MyRunnable class. And it should output that the currently running thread is main thread. Calling run() method on Thread object should behave the same as calling any method on any other object. I hope my answer makes sense to you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The explanation is a bit subtle.

The default behaviour of the `Thread.run()` method is described as running the supplied `Runnable` if it exists, and doing nothing otherwise.

The subtlety is that when a Thread exits, the `exit()` method "aggressively" nulls out reference fields to prevent storage leaks.  (Here's [the source](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Thread.java.html) ... line 720 onwards.) It appears that by the time that you called `t1.run()` in `main`, the thread had exited so the call was a no-op.

Naturally, the output depends on whether or not the `main` thread gets to run again before the child thread exits ... and that will depend on your platform; e.g. what the JVM and the OS-level thread scheduler do and how many cores are available.

Comment: +1 but it might be worth adding that it *may* display `Running: main` depending on thread scheduling (and possibly code reordering? Don't know enough about it to say definitively).

Comment: The explanation by Stephen C does make sense. Thank you. Brian Roach this is true, you can not predict how the scheduling will work. I just couldn't understand why run never executed. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran your code on my machine and I see "Running: main" in the output.

Comment: same:
Running: main
Running: second
Running: first
Running: second
Running: main
Running: first

Comment: Yes ... the output will be platform dependent.  See my answer.